# How do I do multi-line editing in Atom editor?

Tags: text-editors, atom-editor

I've been reading all over and I can't find anything on how to do this in [Atom](http://atom.io) on Windows? And by multi-line editing, I mean being able to expand your cursor across multiple-lines, and being able to type, and that whatever you have typed replicates over all lines you have selected

Answer (score 59, accepted):

IIRC, it is the same as it is with Sublime Text. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and then use the arrow keys to select additional rows. If using the mouse, then just the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is used; the selected locations can be as required, the wouldn't need to be in any particular order.

Atom have a "flight manual" (user manual) with some more detail of the block editing [here](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/editing-and-deleting-text/#multiple-cursors-and-selections).

---

On a Mac when using the mouse, it would be the <kbd>Cmd / ⌘</kbd> key instead of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as on Windows.

---

*Note:*

On Windows, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> could be already mapped by the OS or the screen card drivers/utility to change the screen orientation, for example: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>WINDOWS KEY</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd>

The same would apply on the Mac, e.g.: the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> (as used in Sublime) is often mapped by the OS, so the functionality there takes preference.

In both cases the keybindings can be changed to something else to accommodate both (or turn off the OS, screen card short cuts). The commands are called 'editor:add-selection-above' and 'editor:add-selection-below'

Comment: True. I find in general though that the short cuts using Ctrl only map to the Cmd key on a Mac.

Comment: While the mouse way works, doing Ctrl + Alt and arrows actually turns my screen upside down on Windows..

Comment: @Dean. Thats sounds like you have then shortcut mapped somewhere else then, probably the screen card. You could then remove the shortcut from the screen card driver utility, or create another key mapping for Atom.

Comment: Ctrl+Windows+Alt+arrow keys worked for me in Windows.

Comment: if you use the mouse you still need to use ctrl + alt not just ctrl

Comment: @Aequitas. Interesting, what platform are you on?

Comment: @Niall windows 10 not sure atom version can report on Monday if you're interested

Comment: @Aequitas. Sure, lets see if this is something new.

Comment: @Niall Atom Version 1.21.1

Comment: @Aequitas. That version on Win10 still works for me as described in the answer. Maybe there is a plugin or such (possible even system shortcut) that causes the change.

Comment: I know the question is about Windows, but for the record, on Linux the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kdb>Alt</kdb>+*arrow* combinations are taken by the DE for workspace management.

Comment: So cmd+click did not work for me on mac. This fix did the trick: https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/20804#issuecomment-643279418

Answer (score 30):

For mac users, I found 3 ways:

1. You have a plugin to add support for <kbd>alt</kbd> + *rectangular mouse selection*, called `sublime-style-column-selection`.
2. With <kbd>⌘</kbd> + *mouse click* in multiple places to create multiple cursors.
3. Or without the mouse, there is <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, but you have to **disable the same shortcuts** from *System Preference* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts* used by *Mission Control*: look for `^ ↑` (ie. <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>) and `^ ↓` (ie. <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>).

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for providing the 3rd solution a bit more straight forward than it is in the first answer.

Comment: point 3 worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Install a plugin,

https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor

NOTE: multi-cursor plugin does not show up in Packages menu like some other plugins.

Pressing the following key combo will give you multi line edit,

Windows:
alt up arrow

Linux:
alt shift up arrow

Answer (score 3):

Today I found a package in Atom named "[column-select](https://github.com/ehuss/atom-column-select)". So far it works perfectly fine. The way it works is very close to the implementation of Block selection of Rstudio and Kate.

It does not add space to fill the gap. It literally let you select vertically if there is anything there (skips empty lines and lines that does not have enough length).

The following gif from their Github shows how it works:

[image]